# How to convert time format from h:m:s to hh:mm:ss in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm having problems converting the time display in C++, I tried to think but still couldn't find a solution, so I want to ask how to convert time format from h:m:s to hh:mm:ss in C++???
And this is a example:

5:4:9 --> 05:04:09
I hope someone can help me because I'm new to C++.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with a [mcve]. For more information, please see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Here' a complete program, using standard C++ features<sup>(1)</sup>, which contains a `convert` function that will modify your string as desired:

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::string convert( const std::string &in_str )
{
    std::stringstream in_ss( in_str ), out_ss; // String I/O streams.
    std::string in_field, sep;                 // Field and output separator.

    // Get each field.

    while ( std::getline( in_ss, in_field, ':' ) )
    {
        // Output separator (initially empty) and zero-padded field.

        out_ss << sep << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << stoi(in_field);

        // Update separator for subsequent fields.

        sep = ":";
    }

    // Return string version of the output stream.

    return out_ss.str();
}

int main() {
    // Various test cases.

    for ( const std::string in : { "1:2:3", "1:2:03", "12:34:56", "5:4:9" } )
    {
        std::cout << "'" << in << "' -> '" << convert( in ) << "'\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is (slightly formatted for readability):

```
'1:2:3'    -> '01:02:03'
'1:2:03'   -> '01:02:03'
'12:34:56' -> '12:34:56'
'5:4:9'    -> '05:04:09'
```

The comments in the code should hopefully provide enough detail as to what's happening but it's basically:

1. Read a field.
2. Output the relevant separator followed by the zero-padded field.
3. Return to step 1 if there are more fields.

Note this expects a valid time format, anything else will probably cause issues. I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to add error checking but look for things like `1:2:B` or `1:2:3:4:5`.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> I tend to prefer `std::format` to using string streams but I've avoided that in case you don't have a modern-enough compiler.